# How many people has Han Solo killed?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo, kill-count

During the 4 movies that include Han Solo how many humanoids has he killed? How many creatures or others has he killed as well?

Comment: Let me help make this easier. In ANH, he killed Greedo. He killed stormtroopers in the detention block and TIEs near the Death Star. He killed Vader's wingman.

Comment: In ESB, he killed stormtroopers storming  the Falcon's hangar, he killed TIE pursuers. He killed mynocks. Then he got iced.

Comment: In RotJ, I think he contributed to Boba's (and others') deaths. I'm not sure if he killed any Ewoks. He killed stormtroopers at the shield generator's bunker.

Comment: In TFA, he killed a bunch of pirates. He killed stormtroopers at Maz Kanata's Castle. Then he got iced.

Comment: Wait... when did he get ice-- ohh... right. "Iced".

Comment: This question is nearly impossible to answer fully since there is no way to account for all of his kills in any battle due to any accidental kills or kills due to any explosions that he may have caused and any collateral damage that he could be responsible for. Also since he helped plant the bombs on Starkiller Base then you could say he was partially responsible for that to and there is no way of knowing how many people where on the planet at the time.

Comment: It's easier if we reduce it to deaths he was directly responsible for. Also, the bombs were used to help open a breach for Poe to destroy the base from within - they aren't meant to directly destroy he base outright.

Comment: @thegreatjedi: If you're willing to say that he "contributed" to some kills, then the destruction of 2 Death Stars has to count. He played a critical role in destroying both. Without his involvement, neither Death Star would have been destroyed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to Mr. Sunday Movies](https://youtube.com/watch?v=8oDgViJAxtw), Han Solo killed 42 people onscreen.

Breaking this down, we have:

- Greedo
- Boba Fett
- 38 Imperials/First Orders
- 2 pirates

Comment: The answer to life, the universe, and everything...Now everything makes perfect sense. If we are to include lives he HELPED to end though...

Comment: @thegreatjedi - I was debating whether to put that line in the answer.

Comment: If someone who actually knows the names of the minor characters killed in that video wants to expand...

Comment: The video counts a mynock and the creature from Force Awakens as kills. So in actuality, he only killed 40 people on screen and two creatures.